# SQL calculate complex MRR

Tags: sql, date, sum, common-table-expression

I have been struggling for a few days now on a way to calculate MRR for the table as follows :

| ID | ActualEndDate | CreatedAt | PlanType | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2023-06-09 | 2022-06-10 | Annual | 110 |
| CFR | 2022-08-11 | 2022-06-12 | Mensual | 12 |
| CFR | 2022-08-15 | 2022-07-15 | Mensual | 12 |

**ActualEndDate :** when the subscription is stopping at the moment

**CreatedAt :** when the subscription has started

**PanType :** type of subscription

**Price :** price of subscription

**Monthly price :** price of subscription per month

---

In my case i would like to calculate the MRR as follows :

The annual price should be counted each month (with the monthly price) from the CreatedAt to the ActualEndDate. The mensual price should be counted on the month it’s CreatedAt and then till the ActualEndDate.

I guess this is doable with CTE, but i did not find a good way to do it for now.

In my case i woul like a result as follows :

| Month | MRR |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-06 | 23 |
| 2022-07 | 35 |
| 2022-08 | 35 |

Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

The monthly price column was missing, so I infered the prices

I tested in MySQL, with this table:

**subscriptions:**

| id | ActualEndDate | CreatedAt | PlanType | Price | MonthlyPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2023-06-09 | 2022-06-10 | Annual | 110 | 11 |
| CFR | 2022-08-11 | 2022-06-12 | Mensual | 12 | 12 |
| CFR | 2022-08-15 | 2022-07-15 | Mensual | 12 | 12 |

Check if this suits your needs, I created a Period subtable with the last 6 months, current month and the next six months.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Period.`Month`, '%Y-%m') `Month`,
       COALESCE(SUM(MonthlyPrice), 0) MRR
FROM (
              SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01') AS `Month`
    UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
    UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
    UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
    UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
    UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
    UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 0 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
    UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
    UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 2 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
    UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 3 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
    UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 4 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
    UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
    UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 6 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')) AS Period
LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON Period.`Month` 
                           BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(subscriptions.CreatedAt,'%Y-%m-01') 
                               AND LAST_DAY(subscriptions.ActualEndDate) 
GROUP BY Period.`Month`
```